# extracting adjectives after pos tagging

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Using stanford i want to get all the adjectives in my sentence after doing the pos tagging.I tried some methods and didn't work. Is there any method to get all the Adjectives (JJ) from the sentence.There might be already some questions like this but i didnt find the correct answer.

```
      MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
       String sample = "feeling happy";
       String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);
 System.out.println(tagged);

        output : feeling/VBG happy/JJ
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`MaxentTagger#tagSentence`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html#tagSentence-java.util.List-) method, which returns a list of [`TaggedWord`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/TaggedWord.html) objects.

You can easily filter this resulting list, selecting the `JJ` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tagged the sentence first, after that you will have a list of string in the pair of (word,part of speech tag), since you just need part of speech tag, you can filter it out by looping over all the words in your corpus.
here is a short snippet of python code which is filtering Adjectives from a corpus

```
file=open(product_name,'w');
bags=nltk.bigrams(tagged_sentences)
distribution = nltk.FreqDist(bags)
c = Counter(distribution)
for k,count in c.most_common():
  if ((k[0][1])=='JJ')):
    do something...
```

The above code is in python, so I hope you wont find it difficult to read. First line is opening the file, second is tagging all the words in a corpus. The list returned by c is in format of [(word,tag), (word,tag)....] so you have to check every second index of the list and if it matches the 'JJ' you can filter it out.